# New hard disk making noise

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata, bad-sectors, hard-drive-recovery

I bought a 250GB SATA Seagate hard disk 15 days ago for 70 $ . After formatting for 2 times [I had to for faulty installation] the disk read/write speed have dropped significantly. It's also making the clicking sound, and the systems gets freeze for 1-2 second ! But it works [till now no BSOD or system restart]
What's the problem with the disk ?
I've tried

- Stellar Smart (Early Disk Warning System)
- Disk Check up
- MiniTool Partition Wizard Professional Edition
- Crystal disk info
- HD Tune
- Sea tools [both the windows and CD]

But none of these shows any error on any of these disk.
so what can be the problem ?
I checked the EVENT VIEWER it shows something like this
DISK ERROR WHILE WRITING PAGING INFORMATION ....

I've a 8yr old SEAGATE PATA 80GB hard disk which have been formatted approx 80+ times, but 1 month ago it started showing BSOD, But if i unplug and plug again the disk it works perfectly.

What should i do ?
I tried some software, windows and have also bought a disk
And now i cant buy another new disk [with these high market price :(] & giving it for replacement will take month or months :'(

[image: 250 gb new SATA Disk]

[image: 80 gb old PATA disk]

Comment: Have it replaced before it is too late. Even if the problems go away, you'll never be able to trust it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spin retry count is a measure of how your drive is doing coming up to speed. Increased count shows that something in the subsystem is not allowing the spindle motor to come up to speed in the allotted time.

You have something that is affecting both drives in coming up to speed. Which immediately makes me think of things that two drives would have in common, such as power supplies.

Answer (score -3):

I think it may be a problem with the screws on the disk. The manufacturer probably overtightened them and thats why its making a noise. Its gonna break soon enough if you let it that way. Do not try to tighten them or tighten them yourself though. You'll lose warranty and probably break it. Your best bet is to go to a computer repair shop with special screwdrivers (which will make you lose your warranty) or return and get a new one. Sorry about that.
Thats why i never get seagate or maxtor..Its either fujitsu or WD for me.

Comment: I believe that the case screws are T6 bits. Use a T6 torque driver and slightly loosen the visible ones. The invisible ones cannot be de-tightened without voiding the warranty, unfortunately.

Comment: @Robert what makes you think the drive's screws are too tight?  I've never heard of that happening.

Comment: Doubt that highly. I've disassembled enough of these to tell you that the sheetmetal cover and screws at the top aren't going to affect the spindle motor or solenoid coil head motor as these are placed in some pretty heavy casting quite a distance from the cover attachment screws. Mucking with those will void the warranty, yes they will check for tool marks that indicate tampering if you try to warranty it after fiddling. If it's truly got infant mortality, turn it in on warranty and be done with it.